# NSPersistentContainer: merge policy of viewContext

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using `NSPersistentContainer` to create my Core Data stack. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentcontainer) says that we should use it's `viewContext` property to get the main `NSManagedObjectContext`, but `viewContext` is read-only. What is the default `NSMergePolicy` for this context? Is it possible to change it? For example:

```
storeContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
```

Xcode doesn't complain if I set it in this way, but I'm suspicious about whether this is actually changing the policy since the context is read-only.

**Edit:** For reference, I learned that you can test it with:

```
let type = (defaultContext.mergePolicy as! NSMergePolicy).mergeType
if type == NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType {
    print("Has propertyObjectTrump type")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always possible to change the merge policy on a managed object context. It's writeable, and you can't set it at initialization time, so you set it after creation. The default is probably `NSErrorMergePolicy`, since that's usually the default, but you can change it to whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

The context property is read-only, which means you cannot replace the context itself, however its merge policy property is not, which means you can replace the policy of the read-only context.